# Solving for the shift in a normal curve

Tags: calculus, statistics

Lets say you have a normal curve with a mean of 500 and a standard deviation of 12. I'm not familiar with the mathematical formatting used here and am short on time, so [here's a link that'll format it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F(12*sqrt(2pi)))*e%5E(-((x-500)%5E2)%2F(288)).

So now I'm supposed to find how the curve should be shifted such that 5% of the probabability is below 500. I thought it would be a matter of something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20500%20of%20((1%2F(12sqrt(2pi)))e%5E(-(x-m)%5E2)%2F(288))dx%20%3D%20.05%20solve%20for%20m), because 0 to 500 should yield 5% and I need to know the new mean? However, I guess I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\sigma = 12,$ unchanged by a 'shift' in mean. We seek the new mean $\mu.$
$$.05 = P(X < 500) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{500-\mu}{12}\right)
= P\left(Z < \frac{500-\mu}{12}\right).$$
But from printed tables of the standard normal CDF, $P(Z < -1.645) = .05.$
So $(500 - \mu)/12 = -1.645$ and $\mu = 519.74$. So the shift is $19.74$ to the right.

Check using R statistical software:

```
 pnorm(500, 519.74, 12)
 ## 0.04998491            # as close to 0.05 as possible with tables
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach. The equation is

$P(X\leq x)=\Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu+s}{\sigma} \right)=0.05$

s is the shifting parameter and consequently $\mu-s$ will be the new mean. $\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the Standard Normal distribution. Plugging in the numbers.

$P(X\leq 500)=\Phi\left( \frac{500-500+s}{12} \right)=0.05$

Now calculate the value of s.

Comment: This is fine (+1). Maybe my way is also helpful.

Comment: @BruceET Sure, since it is very similar. :)